# Who is Goddess Vanadurga?

Tags: identification-request, devi

I have heard about the goddess called Vanadurga and I want to know about this goddess. So, my question is:-

- Who is Goddess Vanadurga?
- Is any mention of this goddess in scripture?

Please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

> Ma Vana-durga is conceived with eight arms, in the seven of which, she is required to hold the conch shell, chakra, khadga, khetaka, an arrow, a bow and shula. The remaining hand project the **Tarjani posture(threatening hand posture)**. She possesses the green complexion like the grass
> No less than nine different forms of Ma Durga is present in agamas.Ma Vana Durga is one of them.
> [source](https://archive.org/details/b29002023_0003)

---

[image]

photo courtesy: 
[Sri Kamakoti Mandali](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/2021/03/29/the-rites-of-protection/)

---

> Sri Adi Shankaracharya consecrated the temple of Sri Durgamba in the south of Sringeri.  Owing to the remote location of this temple amongst the woods, the Goddess is famous as Vana Durga.
> When plague threatened Sringeri, Sri Sacchidananda Shiva Abhinava Nrisimha Bharati prayed to Durga and since then not a single case of plague has occurred there.
> Behind the Devi to the right there is a Shiva linga, believed to be an udbhava linga in the name of Mallikarjuna. The origin and time of consecration of this linga is not known. It seems to have been there even before Sri  Adi Shankaracaryas arrival at Sringeri.
> [source](https://sringeri.net/temples/the-guardian-deities/sri-vanadurga)

PS-

*In the Vedic literature, she has been conceived as Aranyani or Vanaspati representing the plants and greenery. In the Atharva Veda she plays an important role influencing the indigenous systems of medicines.*

***Some Temples of Ma Vana-Durga***

(1) [Kathiramangalam Vana-durga Temple](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:VANADURGAI_KADHIRAAMANGALAM_1.jpg)(TN)

(2) Edupalaya Vana Durga Bhavani temple (Telengana)

(3)Chakkulathukavu Temple near Thiruvalla (Kerala)

(4)Sringeri (Karnataka.)